# sigsegv during program execution

Tags: c++, g++

I was writing this problem to submit in spoj, it is running fine on my computer, g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1.But it is giving SIGSEGV on spoj.
here is my code for finding next palindrome, can someone please help.
Also, i tried catching it with signal handler but it never throwed.please help..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool comp(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2) 
{
  if (v1.size() != v2.size()) 
    return v1.size() < v2.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    if (v1[i] != v2[i])
      return v1[i] < v2[i];
  return false;
}

void NextPalindrome(vector<int>& num, int pos1, int pos2) {
    if (pos1 < 0) {
        num[num.size()-1] = 1;
        num.insert(num.begin(), 1);
        return;
    } else if (num[pos1] < 9) {
            num[pos1] = num[pos2] = num[pos1] + 1;
            return;
    } else {
            num[pos1] = num[pos2] = 0;
            NextPalindrome(num, pos1-1, pos2+1);
            return;
    }
}

void ConvertToPalindrome(vector<int>& p, int j, int k)
{
  while (j >= 0)
  {
    if (p[j] != p[k])
      p[k] = p[j];
    j--,k++;
  }
}
int main()
{
  int t;

  cin >> t;
  while (t) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    vector <int> v;
    for (int i = 0;i<s.size(); i++)
      v.push_back(s[i]-'0');
    int size = v.size();
    vector<int> p (v);
    if (size %2 == 0) 
    {
      ConvertToPalindrome(p, size/2-1, size/2);
    }
    else
    {
      ConvertToPalindrome(p, size/2-1, size/2-1);
    }

    if (comp(v,p) == 0) {
      if (size%2 == 0)
        NextPalindrome(p, size/2-1, size/2);
      else
        NextPalindrome(p, size/2, size/2);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<p.size();i++)
      cout << p[i];
    cout << endl;
    t--;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it through a debugger like GDB so at least you have a line number where the problem occurs.

Comment: The only thing is that if v and p are both of size 0, then the second line 2 in NextPalindrome would probably segfault. Also, the second ConvertToPalindrome call from main should probably be have "p, size/2-1, size/2+1". If you pass in 123, you should expect the arguments to be p, 0, 2 not p, 0, 0

Comment: @charles its not giving any error when i ran it on my gdb..

Answer (score 1):

I run gdb to debug your program, the segment fault occurs at line `num[num.size()-1] = 1;` in function `void NextPalindrome(vector<int>& num, int pos1, int pos2)`. When the vector `num` is empty, then the index is out of range. This situation happens when user did not input enough numbers (less than t). You may check whether the input string is empty to avoid this:

```
  while (t) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    if (s.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    ...
   }
```

By the way, the Palindrome logic seems wrong, you can debug yourself.

Comment: its still not solving sigsegv error,please help or suggest how can i debug that..